# NServiceBus, when are too many message used?

Tags: soa, nservicebus

When considering a service in NServiceBus at what point do you start questioning how many messages handled by a service is too much and start to break these into a new service?

Consider the following: I have a sales service which can currently be broken into a few distinct business components, these are sales order validation, sales order processing, purchase order validation and purchase order processing.

There are currently about 20 message handlers and 2 sagas used within this service. My concern is that during high volume traffic from my website this can cause an initial spike in the messages to jump into the hundreds. Considering that the messages need to be processed in the order they are taken off the queue this can cause a delay for the last in the queue ( depending on what processing each message does).

When separating concerns within a service into smaller business components I find this makes things a little easier. Sure, it's a logical separation, but it seems to provide a layer of clarity and understanding. To me it seems it seems an easier option to do this than creating new services where in the end the more services I have the more maintenance I need to do.

Does anyone have any similar concerns to this?

Comment: When messages are processed, do they all read/write to the same database/tables?

Comment: I think I know where you are going with this. The services are separated to different databases with the exception of the saga which manages its own state with Raven.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have actually answered you own question :)

As soon as the message volume reaches a point where the lag becomes an issue you could look to instance your endpoint.  You do not necessarily need to reduce the number of handlers.  You could simply install the service a number of times and have specific message types sent to the relevant endpoint by mapping.

So it becomes a matter of a simple instance installation and some config changes.  So you can then either split messages on sending so that messages from a particular source end up on a particular endpoint (maybe priority) *or* on message type.

I happened to do the same thing on a previous project (not using NServiecBus though) where we needed document conversion messages coming from the UI to be processed ASAP.  We simply installed the conversion service again with its own set of queues and changed the UI configuration to send the conversion messages to the new endpoint.  The background conversion messages were still going to the previous endpoint.  So here the source determined the separation.

Comment: Agreed, it seems much like a trial and error scenario where you have to see what works in the production environment. I've always been a fan of queues in the sense that it's a robust form of messaging however the times when messages flurry through due to load can put a damper on things. I think once you've named a service you try to force message to fit and it may not always be the best case. It's nice to know I'm not the only one pondering these thoughts, cheers.